# AngularJS - Why watcher is removed?

Tags: angularjs

I am new to AngularJS and I follow a long with some tutorial to get started. In one tutorial it shows how to remove watcher with the example below:

```
$scope.breakit = $scope.$watch('mydata.val',function(newval){
    $scope.mydata.toolong = newval.length >3;
})

<button ng-click="breakit()">Break It</button>
```

It works, but what I don't understand is why is it calling that `breakit` function will remove the watcher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$scope.$watch` [returns a function that deregisters the watcher](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch) when called.

Answer (score 1):

$watch in angularjs returns a deregistration function, calling it would deregister the $watcher this is what explained in example you are going through.

now question is when you would want to unwatch an expression. Its simple when it would be of no use for you (as its consist of performance). e.g like in your code shown above,

Its setting a variable $scope.mydata.toolong = 1 when value is greater than 3 might be for some validation purpose but its also providing you a button "Break it" if you want to enter the value greater than 3 to just break the validation by deregistration function watch.